# How do I increment one file ten times

Tags: file, for-loop, compiler-errors, syntax-error, increment

How can I increment one file ten times?  Does it involve for(i = 0, i < 10, i++).  Most of what I have came across is about looping integers or opening multiple different files.  The code I'm working with is below.  Thanks for the help.

```
const char *path="/Desktop/Libraries/Documents" ;
ofstream myfile(path);
myfile.open ("howyoulike.doc") ;
myfile << "How you like math\n" ;
myfile.close();
```

So, I edited my code to such:

```
const char *path="/Desktop/Libraries/Documents" ;
const char * FILENAMES[] ={"file1.doc", "file2.doc", "file3.doc", "file4.doc", "file5.doc"};    
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
ofstream myfile(path);
myfile.open (FILENAMES[i]) ;
myfile << "How you like math?\n" ;
myfile.close();
```

### Now I'm getting c2228 error "left of .open/.close must have class/struct/union type is unknow-type".  Any suggestions on how to fix?

Executable/Run Code that is now part of my program.  Thanks for the help!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

struct pizza{
string FILENAMES[9];
};

int main ()
{

int i;

pizza greg = {"file1.doc", "file2.doc", "file3.doc", "file4.doc", "file5.doc"};

cout << "Input is invalid.  Program will end. " << "\n" ;
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
const char *path="/Desktop/Libraries/Documents" ;
    ofstream myfile(path);
    myfile.open (greg.FILENAMES[i]) ;
    myfile << "How you like math?\n" ;
    myfile.close();
};

return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by incrementing a file? I can imagine if you would like to increment data inside a file, but the file itself... doesn't make much sense to me?

Comment: hi Ivan, what I would like, and have done, is created a program that will produce a file on my desktop.  Now I'm wondering how I can make that program create ten of those files on my desktop.  Without repeating the code ten times.  - David

Comment: Well, since you can't make files with same names on the same location, you can't do that (because they get overwritten every time). Either store your documents on different locations or change their name. That in combination with a for loop should do the trick!

Comment: So found code online that seems to be adaptable to the use I want, but error c2228 message.  Any suggestions?

Comment: MSDN says: The operand to the left of the period (.) is not a class, structure, or union. Check that out! [link]http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3y365xw6%28v=vs.90%29.aspx